# REACT.JS - How to invoke login using react-openidconnect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, openid-connect

I am trying to use **react-openidconnect**. Its my first touch with OAuth and OpenIdConnect. I did everything as in example (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-openidconnect) but i have no idea how to redirect to login page provided by Auth Server. I tried to google it, but didn't find anything.

Answer (score 4):

Usually you either redirect as a result of one of these actions:

- Clicking a login button
- As a result of not having a valid access token and being able to call an API

In both cases you issue an Authorize Redirect by calling **userManager.signInRedirect**.

See [this class](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample1/blob/master/spa/src/plumbing/oauth/authenticator.ts) for an example.

Out of interest I have some visual tutorials on my blog to explain how to integrate the oidc-client library, which your wrapper library uses.

- [Initial SPA Code Sample](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample1)
- [Write Up](https://authguidance.com/2017/09/24/basicspa-overview/)

If it helps, my blog also has some more advanced posts and samples, including one in [ReactJS](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample.final).

Answer (score 1):

The JSX that is set in `renderNotAuthenticated` (so e.g. the `<div>You are not authenticated, please click here to authenticate.</div>` in the [docs](https://github.com/bsvveen/React-OpenIdConnect/blob/master/README.md)) is rendered inside a clickable `div` element (see the [source](https://github.com/bsvveen/React-OpenIdConnect/blob/479ad9888580a406824ac9114db1f053a991a6c5/src/index.js#L76) for details), so you should be redirected with a click on that.

In case you don't get redirected, you should see an error in the browser's console.